# Why does python Requests lib work in command prompt, but gives me [Errno 11004] when implemented in Django?

Tags: python, django, view, python-requests

I searched for similar questions and suspect this to be a proxy setting issue after searching Stack Overflow, but I am just wondering why for example requests.get('http://google.com') returns the correct response without any errors when executed in cmd on a windows 7 machine, but when I start making requests in my django project and use the manage.py runserver test site, I get the following error:

```
CONNECTIONERROR: Max retries exceeded with url: (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)
```

I assume the problem is the test server that you are running with manage.py since the code works in cmd. Thanks in advance for any explanations of why this is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DNS lookup is failing on your server. You should investigate why your server cannot resolve the domain name you're using.

Comment: Thanks. So is the problem from my end or the actual request.get that is failing to retrieve the information from the server on the web or is the problem my server? For the record, I am trying to use requests.get on the facebook graph api so basically requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/<username>')

Comment: The problem is your server. Your server performs a DNS lookup to turn `graph.facebook.com` into an IP address. This lookup is failing, so the request never gets off the box. You should investigate why this lookup is failing.